# How to receive the value in the form submit php

Tags: php

```
<select name="gender" id="Gender">
<option selected="selected" value="woman">女士</option>
<option value="man">先生</option>
</select>
```

the above code is in a form, when submit the form to test.php. how to get the selected value?女士 or 先生.

i know this can get.

```
if($_POST['gender']=='woman'){
$_POST['gender']="女士";
}else{
$_POST['gender']="先生";
}
```

is there a way to get the text. thank you

Comment: *"get the text"* what text are you referring to ?

Comment: No. The displayed dropdown text is never sent as form payload. You'll have to keep using a map.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. `==` is a *comparison* operator, you're testing for equality in both branches of the `if` statement. There is no effect; both branches of the `if` statement do nothing.

Comment: @Dagon the text in option label

Answer (score 3):

Use the option text as option value. Like this,

```
<option selected="selected" value="女士">女士</option>
<option value="先生">先生</option>
```

But keep in mind any one can change the gender and become something else.

```
<option value="transexual">transexual</option>
```

To prevent this its better you also maintain a white list in the server side code.

```
$gender == isset($_POST['gender'])?  $_POST['gender']: "";
if(!in_array(array("女士", "先生"), $gender)){
    $gender = "先生"; // set the default gender.
}
```